# Grouping with sum of a key value in JavaScript array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of object like below

```
var data = [{monthName: "Jun", name:'web', number: 1, month: 6}, 
{monthName: "Jul", name:'web', number: 2, month: 7},
{monthName: "Aug", name:'web', number: 2, month: 8}, 
{monthName: "Jun", name:'sales', number: 12, month: 6}, 
{monthName: "Jul", name:'sales', number: 2, month: 7}]
```

I want to group the data based on key "name" and then need to get the number as an array.

Sample output like below

```
datasets: [{
     name: 'web',
     number: [1, 2, 2],
       },{
    name: 'sales',
    number: [12, 2]
         }]
```

I am not sure about how to group data and then get a key value as array.

I have grouped the data using below code

```
result = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
             r[a.name] = r[a.name] || [];
             r[a.name].push(a);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));
```

But not sure about how to get the desired output. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While reducing, also build up the wanted result objects if the key doesn't exist yet:

```
  const result = [];
  { // Make hash viable to GCing after this operation
    const hash = Object.create(null);
    for(const { name, number } of data) {
       if(!hash[name])
         result.push({ name, numbers: hash[name] = [] });
       hash[name].push(number);
    }
  }
```

Comment: is there any way to get the  iteration number  also in this example ?I mean here we have two objects in the array so the first object's iteration number will be 1 and second one's will be 2 like that ?

Comment: hi the given solution is counting in each steps, i mean for the first item it is coming as 0 as index and for the next item its 3 because the inner loop for creating the number [] also counts here

Comment: Ah, at the end do `result.forEach((entry, index) => Object.assign(entry, { index }))`, but its unclear why you need that, I mean you can easily get the index with `.indexOf`

Comment: no problem i have just used result.length inside, solved the issue . thanks for the wonderful solution

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to check if the array has an object with the `name` , if it does, append the number to it, otherwise push a new object :

```js
var data = [
  { monthName: "Jun", name: "web", number: 1, month: 6 },
  { monthName: "Jul", name: "web", number: 2, month: 7 },
  { monthName: "Aug", name: "web", number: 2, month: 8 },
  { monthName: "Jun", name: "sales", number: 12, month: 6 },
  { monthName: "Jul", name: "sales", number: 2, month: 7 }
];

var result = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const ndx = acc.findIndex(e => e.name === curr.name);

  if (ndx > -1) {
    acc[ndx].number.push(curr.number);
  } else {
    acc.push({
      name: curr.name,
      number: [curr.number]
    });
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're answer is almost correct, just add an additional line to push to a `number` array:

```js
var data = [{monthName: "Jun", name: 'web', number: 1, month: 6},
 {monthName: "Jul", name: 'web', number: 2, month: 7},
 {monthName: "Aug", name: 'web', number: 2, month: 8},
 {monthName: "Jun", name: 'sales', number: 12, month: 6},
 {monthName: "Jul", name: 'sales', number: 2, month: 7}];

result = Object.values(data.reduce(function (r, {name, number}) {
 r[name] = r[name] || {name, number: []};
 r[name].number.push(number);
 return r;
}, {})).map((v, i) => ({...v, iteration: i + 1}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: is there any way to get the iteration number also in this example ?I mean here we have two objects in the array so the first object's iteration number will be 1 and second one's will be 2 like that ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a map which groups the entries with `reduce`, then get the entries of the map with `Object.entries` and iterate over them with `map`, creating a new object for each in the process.

```js
var data = [{monthName:"Jun",name:"web",number:1,month:6},{monthName:"Jul",name:"web",number:2,month:7},{monthName:"Aug",name:"web",number:2,month:8},{monthName:"Jun",name:"sales",number:12,month:6},{monthName:"Jul",name:"sales",number:2,month:7}];

function mergeName(arr) {
  let map = data.reduce((a,c) => (a[c.name] = ({...c, 
            number: a[c.name] && a[c.name].number
                    ? a[c.name].number.push(c.number) && a[c.name].number 
                    : [c.number]}),a),{});
  return Object.entries(map).map(o => ({name: o[0], number: o[1].number}))
}

console.log(mergeName(data))
```